# CustomScrollView with ExpansionPanelList.radio in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to use list ExpansionTile with radio behavior (one tile opened per click), but during of coding found that customization of ExpansionTile brings to animation loss. So I tried to find another solution, so I've found ExpansionPanelList.radio. Then it brings me to this:
I have a parent CustomScrollView with ExpansionPanelList.radio. But it doesn't render at all. Here is parent view:

```
Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        MainSliverAppBar(
          onLanguagePressed: () {},
          onCallPressed: () {},
        ),
        SliverPadding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(PaddingSmall),
          sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: ActionHeader(
                headerTitle: _parseProductsActionHeader(context),
                background: LightGreyColor),
          ),
        ),
        SliverFillRemaining(
          child: CategoriesList(     ///ExpansionPanelList.radio
              categories: Category.categories,
              onCategoryTapped: (int categoryID) {}),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: BottomEmptySpace(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _parseProductsActionHeader(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(getTranslation(context, 'categories'),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style:
            Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.copyWith(color: BlackColor));
  }
```

This is ExpansionPanelList.radio as CategoryList:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpansionPanelList.radio(
      
      children: categories
          .map(
            (category) => _createCategoryPanel(context, category),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  }

  ExpansionPanelRadio _createCategoryPanel(
      BuildContext context, Category category) {
    return ExpansionPanelRadio(
      value: Key(category.id.toString()),
      headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: ImageIcon(
            AssetImage(category.image),
            size: 32.0,
            color: PrimaryColor,
          ),
          title: Text(category.name),
        );
      },
      body: _createChildrenCategories(context, category.children),

    );
  }

  Widget _createChildrenCategories(
      BuildContext context, List<Category> categories) {
    return ListView(
      children: categories
          .map(
            (category) => _createChildCategory(context, category),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  }

  Widget _createChildCategory(BuildContext context, Category childCategory) {
    return Ink(
      color: LightGreyColor,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(PaddingMedium),
      child: InkWell(
        highlightColor: PrimaryColor.withAlpha(20),
        splashColor: PrimaryColor.withAlpha(20),
        onTap: onCategoryTapped(childCategory.id) ?? () {},
        child: Text(childCategory.name),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And very nice Exception for beginner(me):

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderDecoratedBox#236ac NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    ExpansionPanelList 
lib\…\categories\categories_list.dart:14
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I did the same with nestedScrollView, but getting same error.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExpansionPanelList should be wrapped with SingleChildScroll view with NeverScrollableScrollPhysics():

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView (
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child: ExpansionPanelList.radio(
            dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        expandedHeaderPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: categories
            .map<ExpansionPanelRadio>((category) => _createCategoryPanel(context, category)
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In addition, no need in using SliverFillRemaining(child items cutting), better to use SliverToBoxAdapter.